# phantomjs - enormous memory usage

Tags: linux, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using selenium with phantom-js web driver on linux virtual machine.
as it seems each instance of phantom is consuming too much memory, after three instances the virtual machine crashes and i must restart the machine.

[image: top command]

is there a way to guaranty that the virtual machine won't crashes or to reduce the enormous memory usage of phantom?

```
service_args = [
                    '--ignore-ssl-errors=true',
                    '--proxy=' + proxyIP + ':' + str(proxyPort),
                    '--proxy-type=http',
                    ]
self.browser = Browser(driver_name="phantomjs", service_args=service_args)
```

Comment: I was faced with the same issue and decided to implement just as you did, releasing the PhantomJS driver (along with its process) when I'm done with it and restarting it when I need it again.

Comment: yeah, it's kind of ugly workaround but it is what it is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after research, I found that phantomjs can cause memory leaks, from my understanding the best solution is to check the memory usage of phantom every interval of time and if it exceeds a threshold, than close the phantom and reopen again. that's the best solution I could find to workaround the problem for now.